# DataTemplateSelector crashes in UWP

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I have loaded multiple labels inside my ListView using `Grid`. I want to change the position of labels when I rotate the screen.

So I did something like this.

```
protected override void OrientationChanged(OrientationValu newOrientation)
    {
        RdMyListView.ItemTemplate = null;
        if (newOrientation == OrientationValu.Landscape)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LAndscape");
            viewModel.IsLandscape = true;
            RdMyListView.ItemTemplate = new OrientationDataTemplateSelector
                {
                    LandscapeTemplate = landscapeTemplate,
                    PortraitTemplate = portraitTemplate,
                    IsLandscape = true
                };

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Portrait");
            viewModel.IsLandscape = false;


                RdMyListView.ItemTemplate = new OrientationDataTemplateSelector
                {
                    LandscapeTemplate = landscapeTemplate,
                    PortraitTemplate = portraitTemplate,
                    IsLandscape = false
                };


        }
    }
```

This is how I call to the datatemplator class and get the `DataTmplate`. When my `Page` loads I assigned my private 2 data templates like this.

```
        landscapeTemplate = GetDataTemplate(true);
        portraitTemplate = GetDataTemplate(false);
```

Based on this true or false my `GetDataTemplate(bool isLandscape)` will return different data templates.

```
private DataTemplate GetDataTemplate (bool isLandscape)
    {
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {

          // Implementation

       });
    return dataTemplate;
```

}

But UWP app crashes when maximize the simulator window. Android works fine. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: It would help if you include the error details.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Value was an invalid value for ItemTemplate This is what I am getting